# Synchronization issues when two threads try to write to same tcp socket simultaneouslu

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have 20 threads all sending data on single tcp socket at a time and receiving data as well. When I run my application I don’t see any synchronization issues but according to my understanding, there may be some issues when two threads simultaneously try to write to tcp socket or when one thread is writing while other is reading.

If my understanding is correct, why don’t I face any errors?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yep, I missed the first part of the question and was answering the bit about one reader + one writer.  Misleading comment removed.

Comment: Try to see the difference using even more threads ,May be you can see some difference.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes when you don't look both ways before crossing the street, you still get to the other side of the street safely. That doesn't mean it will work successfully every time you do it.

Here's the thing, you say "you don't see any synchronization issues", but that's only because it happens to do what you want it to do. Flip this around -- the reason you don't see any synchronization issues is because you happen to want it to do what it happens to do. Someone who expected it to do something else *would* see synchronization issues with the very same code.

In other words, you flipped a coin that could come up heads or tails. You expected it to come up heads, knowing that it was not guaranteed. And it came up heads. There's no mystery -- the explanation is that you expected what it happened to do. Had you expected something else, even had it done the very same thing, it would not have done what you expected.

Answer (score 6):

First, the send and receive streams of each socket are independent.  There should be no problem with one thread sending while another is receiving.

If multiple threads attempt to write to one socket, the behaviour is, in general, undefined.  In practice, a write call from one of the threads will get into a lock in the TCP stack state-machine first, preventing any other threads from entering, write its data, release the lock and exit the stack, so allowing write calls from other threads to proceed.  The would allow single write calls to be serialized.  If your protocol implementation can send all PDU's with one write call, then fine.  If a PDU requires more than one write call, then your outgoing PDU's can get sliced as the write calls from the multiple threads get interleaved.

Making receive calls from multiple threads to one socket is just... something. Even if the stack internal synchro allows only one receive call per socket at a time, the streaming nature of TCP would surely split up the received data in a pseudo-arbitrary manner across the threads.  Just don't do it, it's crazy.

TCP already has a mechanism for multiplexing data streams - multiple sockets.  You should use them correctly.

If you need to multiplex data streams across one socket, you should add a data routing protocol on top of TCP and implement this protocol in just one receive thread.  This thread can keep a list of virtual connections and so service stream/message requests from other threads.